# Ionic 2 - Native File issue with JSON.parse on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic2

I'm having a problem when deploying my Ionic2 app on iOS real device. Testing it in web and Android real device works fine but when running my app on a iPhone I have a problem when parsing data retrieved from reading a local file (using @ionic-native/file).

After checking that the file exists, I read it like this:

```
this.file.readAsText(this.file.cacheDirectory + 'epg/', fileName)
.then( (data) => {
    console.log('read file - then 1');
    console.log(data);
    this.channels = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('read file - then 2');
```

Debugging it in Xcode console I see this:

"read file - then 1"

"(empty string)"

"TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57" (4 times)

It never gets to the second log, but it neither has an error in the logs....

When I run it in android device, I get the first log, then all the data read from the file and then the second log and everything works fine but in iOS it stops in the 'JSON.parse' line without error but the device continue in a loading state and it never stops. Seems like there were an error but no error detected...

Any help? Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you sure you are using `@ionic-native/native-storage` to read files?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I am using @ionic-native/file. Typed wrongly the name of the library (should sleep more.... ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page: https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/#rewriting-file

You should try using `normalizeURL(this.file.cacheDirectory + 'epg/')`

Comment: normalize URL parse my url:
file:///var/mobile/Containers/D....
to
http://localhost:8080/var/mobile/Containers/D...

and now I'm having a '{"code":5,"message":"ENCODING_ERR"}'

Answer (score 0):

Solved it removing the platform (*ionic cordova platform rm ios*) and installing it again!